# MYSQL - how to summarize data from one table based on values from another?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables. One called users where I store users name. The other store it's posts (post type, date, etc). The 3rd table can store different metakeys and values according to the type of the post. 
I want to summarize the posts from each user for example:
To have one's name followed by the meta key and values associated with his posts.

Hard to find out some multiple joins, but failed all day long.

My tables are acording to the links: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/cc7cd/2/0 and  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/cc7cd/3/0

I would like to have a query that returns the fooling result (the example show one line, but it could have one line for each date):

```
User display name      date (meta-key = data_de_inicio_do_servico)   date (meta-key = turno )        number of days (count number of instances that each user was found in that meta_key = data_de_inicio_do_servico)

1S BMT LEVI José da Silva Melo         07/05/2014                     06:45 às 15:45                                              1
```

Comment: This is confusing question because you have different column labels for all 3 queries.

Comment: You can join tables and assign aliases. You have a fairly complicated table structure, and without an SQLFiddle no one will be able to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, are you trying to create a union between these three queries? Rather than a join?

For example,

```
select 
    wp_posts.ID
    , wp_postmeta.meta_key
    , wp_postmeta.meta_value
from wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta
    ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
where
    wp_posts.post_type like '%_an' AND
    (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'data_de_inicio_do_servico' OR
    wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'turno') AND
    wp_postmeta.meta_value not like ''
union all
select 
    wp_postmeta.post_id as ID,
    wp_postmeta.meta_key , 
    wp_postmeta.meta_value 
from wp_postmeta 
where (wp_postmeta.meta_key like '%ATCO%' or wp_postmeta.meta_key like 'operador%') 
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value in (select wp_users.display_name from wp_users)
```

Comment: My apologies. Overlooked the column aliases. Ignore my response :)

Answer (score 0):

First, I can easily get the first two, but slightly simplified with aliases for readability.
"p" for the wp_POSTS table, and "pm1" for the first post meta-data table, "pm2" for the second.
"pm3" for the last was a little bit more effort...  I changed from and "AND IN" for the users table to a left-join... however you can change that to a JOIN if you ONLY want those that are associated with the "users" table as pm3 alias would indicate.

This is probably MUCH close to what you are looking for.

```
SELECT
      p.ID,
      pm1.meta_key AS 'Date of duty', 
      pm1.meta_value AS 'Date',
      pm2.meta_key AS 'Turn of duty', 
      pm2.meta_value AS 'Turn',
      pm3.meta_key AS 'Operator', 
      pm3.meta_value AS 'Name'
   from 
      wp_posts p
         LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm1
            ON p.ID = pm1.post_id
           AND pm1.meta_key = 'data_de_inicio_do_servico'
           AND pm1.meta_value not like ''

         LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm2
            ON p.ID = pm2.post_id
           and pm2.meta_key = 'turno'
           AND pm2.meta_value not like ''

         LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm3
            ON p.ID = pm3.post_id
           and (    pm3.meta_key like '%ATCO%' 
                 or pm3.meta_key like 'operador%' )
           LEFT JOIN wp_users u
              ON wp3.meta_value = u.display_name
   where
      p.post_type like '%_an' 
   order by 
      p.post_date DESC
```

To help optimize the query, I would have an index on your 
wp_posts table on (post_type, post_date, id )
wp_postmeta table on (post_id, meta_key )
wp_users table on (display_name)  (if you really NEED to keep this one)